# Problem with Marshal class

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, native, import

I was going through my Win32 class today to work on some long-needed improvements. I am stuck on my disk geometry code. On the

> var ob =
>   (DiskGeometry)Marshal.PtrToStructure(geomp,
>   typeof (DiskGeometry));

line, it keeps throwing an exception..

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

My code is..

```
        if (Handle.IsInvalid)
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            return new DiskGeometry();
        }
        var geom = new DiskGeometry();
        var geomp = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(geom));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(geom, geomp, false);
        uint returnedBytes;
        if (!DeviceIoControl(Handle, (uint) IOCTL_CONTROL_CODE_CONSTANTS.IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref geomp, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DiskGeometry)), out returnedBytes, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
            return new DiskGeometry();
        }
        var ob = (DiskGeometry)Marshal.PtrToStructure(geomp, typeof (DiskGeometry));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the definition for `DiskGeometry`?

Comment: Have you changed anything else? Has the `DiskGeometry` structure changed? What about the code above what you're showing us? I'm curious where `Handle` comes from.

Comment: The struct never changes as far as I know. And this is the branch of code that calls the code I defined in my main post: http://pastie.org/1324214

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//you don't need to instantiate the managed type before this
var geomp = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DiskGeometry)));

//remove this
Marshal.StructureToPtr(geom, geomp, false);
```

You just need to allocate a block of memory that DiskIoControl will populate with an unmanaged type. After your pointer is referencing that data, then you marshal it to your managed type.

You can also check `Marshal.GetlastWin32Error()` for `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` after calling `DeviceIoControl` and make sure that `returnedBytes == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DiskGeometry))`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to work. I also changed it back to a uint and it had no affect either.

Comment: @Eaton - What about checking that geomp is not zero before trying to marshal back?

Comment: geomp is 60801 in length before it hits the ob declaration.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have never really messed with pointers and Marshal until now. But anyway, that condition is true. It is not 0.

Comment: I edited my answer. I think the fact that you've already assigned your managed object to that block might cause you problems.

Comment: I revised my code based on your edit, but it still throws the same exception. http://pastie.org/1324288

Comment: I made one more edit for some error checking. I looked at the DISK_GEOMETRY definition, and I can almost guarantee it's that MEDIA_TYPE typedef that's screwing you up. Can you show your managed MEDIA_TYPE definition?

Comment: Ok, first, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 0. And returnedBytes == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DiskGeometry)). Both of those are true. Also, when I used this code before, it did work, but i didn't like how I had to change the param for DIO. http://pastie.org/1324316

Answer (score 0):

When marshaling from unmanaged memory to managed memory, "*Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*" errors are a good indication that you do not have the appropriate permissions to access the memory location specified at the given pointer location.

These are the definitions used to validate your code works fine:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, uint dwIoControlCode,
        IntPtr lpInBuffer, uint nInBufferSize,
        IntPtr lpOutBuffer, uint nOutBufferSize,
        out uint lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

(other code omitted)

```
IntPtr Handle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", (EFileAccess)0, EFileShare.Read | EFileShare.Write, IntPtr.Zero, ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting, (EFileAttributes)0, IntPtr.Zero);

            var geom = new DiskGeometry();
            var geomp = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(geom));
            uint returnedBytes = 0;

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(geom, geomp, false);

            if (!DeviceIoControl(Handle, (uint)IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, IntPtr.Zero, 0, geomp, 
                (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DiskGeometry)), 
                out returnedBytes, 
                IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());
                return;
            }

            var ob = (DiskGeometry)Marshal.PtrToStructure(geomp, typeof(DiskGeometry));
```

Comment: Updated code, still not working. http://pastie.org/1325666 I have spent about 7 hours trying to fix a process that was meant to be a 5 minute job.. Anymore ideas? I am getting REALLY frustrated with this. Happy Thanksgiving!